# Hide elements in reversed order

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some notifications, that are categorized in some groups. I want when I click on the "X" to clear all notifications in this group in Mobile OS (style). In reversed order with 1 second delay.

So far I've done this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#activity a.close-btn").click(function () {
        $.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
        var title = $(this).parent();
        var notifications = $(this).parent().next('ul');

        notifications.find('li').reverse().each(function (i, value) {
            if (i != 0) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(value).hide('slide', {
                        direction: 'right'
                    }, 1000);
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                $(value).hide('slide', {
                    direction: 'right'
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It removes the first element of this group and then (a second later) removes the rest of them.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FakeHeal/65spykvr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the timeout, you are calling all elements with a delay of 1 second

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#activity a.close-btn").click(function () {
        $.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
        var title = $(this).parent();
        var notifications = $(this).parent().next('ul');

        notifications.find('li').reverse().each(function (i, value) {
            if (i != 0) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(value).hide('slide', {
                        direction: 'right'
                    }, 1000);
                }, (i + 1) * 1000);
            } else {
                $(value).hide('slide', {
                    direction: 'right'
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You could improve this further by removing the condition of i != 0 and instead use the following:

setTimeout(function () {

                $(value).hide('slide', {
                    direction: 'right'
                }, 1000);
            }, 1000 * i);

I created an updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/65spykvr/1/